# Do I need the Dawnguard DLC to get the dragon plate armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm ready to install the dawnguard DLC for skyrim because I want to get access to the dragon plate armor, but I did a little research and I'm not sure if dragon plate is in the game or I need to install the Dawnguard DLC.

Answer (score 3):

No, [Dragonplate Armor](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonplate_Armor#Dragonplate_Armor) does not require the Dawnguard DLC. It does not require any DLC, as it is simply the heavy armor set of the Dragonbone material.

Dawnguad is required for the [Dragonbone Weapons](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Armor#Dragonbone_Weapons), though.